# Why can't I use the ternary ? operator to select between two function calls?

Tags: java

I was recently programming and ran into an issue using the ? : operand. Here's my code.

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        rand.nextInt(1) == 0 ? vertShip(board) : horizShip(board);
    }
```

My compiler throws me an error stating that the left hand side of the line (rand.nextInt(1) == 0 ) must be a variable. I've tried variants such as

```
    Random rand = new Random();
    int a = rand.nextInt(1);
    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        a == 0 ? vertShip(board) : horizShip(board);
    }
```

or if statements in the left hand side but they don't fix the problem. Would anyone be able to help me?

Comment: What's the actual error message?

Comment: This looks OK. What's the *exact* error message? Also, `rand.nextBoolean()` is probably simpler.

Comment: "Syntax error on token "==", invalid AssignmentOperator"
and also, "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not every expression is a statement. Use an `if` statement here. See Section [14.8 Expression Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.8) in the Java SE 7 Java Language Specification.

> Certain kinds of expressions may be used as statements by following
>   them with semicolons.
>
> ```
> ExpressionStatement:
>     StatementExpression ;
>
> StatementExpression:
>     Assignment
>     PreIncrementExpression
>     PreDecrementExpression
>     PostIncrementExpression
>     PostDecrementExpression
>     MethodInvocation
>     ClassInstanceCreationExpression
> ```

Examples of expression statement for each of the above:

```
x = y;
++x;
--x
x++;
x--;
fn(); // Or donkey.fn();, etc.
new Donkey(this);
```

What you can't do is:

```
b ? f() : g();
f() + g();
```

However, if you're dead set on obfuscating your code, I guess you could write:

```
fn(a == 0 ? vertShip(board) : horizShip(board));
(a == 0 ? vertShip(board) : horizShip(board)).fn();
```

(I think. I don't have a compiler to hand and wouldn't usually write such code.)

Answer (score 3):

The compiler is right. The ternary operator returns something, so you need to assign it to a variable.

Comment: So do many function calls, but we don't necessarily assign the results to anything.

Answer (score 3):

Java isn't perl. Use an if statement:

```
 if (rand.nextInt(1) == 0) {
    vertShip(board);
 } else { 
    horizShip(board);
 }
```

You can't build a function call statement by sticking the ternary ? on the front.

Comment: In Perl you could actually abstract the common bits out: `($rand->nextInt(1) == 0 ? \&vertShip : \&horizShip)->($board);`

Comment: yes, well, and you could solve the travelling salesman problem in 4 characters, too.

Comment: OK, I couldn't. John Skeet can.

Comment: Just for fun, here's a Haskell version: `(if nextInt rand 1 == 0 then vertShip else horizShip) board`

Answer (score 1):

```
a == 0 ? vertShip(board) : horizShip(board); // is an expression
if (a == 0) vertShip(board); else horizShip(board); // is a statement
```

Compare:

```
if (condition) 
{
    execute statement(s)
}
else
{
    execute statement(s)
}
```

With:

```
 expression1 ? expression2 : expression3
```

Use the appropriate construct.